# Neutron density PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

On *Mathews and Walker's book exercise (8-2)*

- We are given that the neutron density n inside $U_{235}$ obeys the differential equation
  $$\nabla ^2u+\lambda u=\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial{n}}{\partial{t}} \;\;\;\;,$$ 
  *$ n=0 $ on surface*

and we are ask to find the critical radius $R_0$ such that the neutron density inside a $U_{235}$ sphere of radius $R_0$ or greater is unstable and increases exponentially with time.

- Also Suppose two hemispheres, each just barely stable, are brought together to form
  a sphere. This sphere is unstable, with $n$~$e^{t/τ }$,where
  Find the “time-constant” τ of the resulting explosion.

I do the separation of variable $n=R(\vec{r})T(t)$ and I get that
$$\frac{\nabla^2R}{R}+\lambda=m$$
$$\frac{T'}{T}=km$$
I choose $m>0$ so the T(t) is unstable and increase exponentially over time.
So i get $$T =Ce^{km}$$ 
and
$$R''+\frac{2}{r}R'+(\lambda-m)R=0$$
but I can't see how this can lead to find the $R_0$ which the density will increase with time , probably because I already set the time to diverge ,but i can't see how this will get to diverge otherwise.

Any *hint* please :) ?

Comment: any starting point ?